# Take ownership of registry key via registry script?

Tags: windows-7, permissions, windows-registry

I have come across some registry edits/hacks I'd like to make.  however, it appears that you have to take control of some registry keys before you can make the edit.  In the [articles](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-take-ownership-permission-of-a-registry-key-in-windows/), this is a [manual process](https://www.howtogeek.com/77878/take-ownership-of-or-assign-full-permission-for-a-registry-key-in-windows-7/), though VG does go into some [other options](http://www.askvg.com/windows-tip-take-ownership-permission-of-registry-keys-from-command-line/).

However, I'd like to be able to run 1 .reg file to accomplish 1 task, including taking ownership of the registry key I am trying to modify or add.  Is that possible?

If that's not possible, then how likely is it that I can drop out to Power Shell to perform the take ownership and registry key?  I know Power Shell can do the latter, but I'm not sure about the former.  In this case, have 1 script file is my goal, even if it isn't a .reg script, but a Power Shell one.

Comment: [Take Ownership (Permission) of Registry Keys from Command Line](http://www.askvg.com/windows-tip-take-ownership-permission-of-registry-keys-from-command-line/)

Comment: I linked to that in the OP.  Those options are not related to a registry file; they are command line programs that won't work in a registry file.  Some of the programs have to be downloaded.

Comment: You can't change registry permissions using a .reg file, but you can change the registry using a .bat file. So the entire thing can be scripted in a .bat file, thats what @DavidPostill means by referring to that link.

Comment: Exactly what @LPChip said.

Comment: You have to change the permissions first or the reg file will fail.

Comment: [Changing Permissions in the Registry](https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/08/28/controlling-registry-acl-permissions-with-powershell/) shows you how to do it with PowerShell.

Comment: So, it sounds like at least I can do it all in one file.  That's cool.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't have any built-in cmdlet to do so, but you can use directly the Microsoft.Win32.Registry functions to pull this off.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044432/how-do-i-take-ownership-of-a-registry-key-via-powershell 
https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/lean-and-mean-snippets-for-power-users-runasti-reg_own-toggledefender-updated-2022-05-22.83479/#post-1658809 ([mirror](https://github.com/AveYo/LeanAndMean/blob/main/reg_own.ps1))